# finding max and min in a stack and swap it without disturbing the other elements

Tags: data-structures

Example if you have a stack

2
     48
     **1**
     32
     24
     12
     **60**

Then after operation it should look like

2
    48
    **60**
    32
    24
    12
    **1**

Comment: a lot of things but bringing the orignal stack back witout hampering the sequence is a problem.

Comment: Can you provide some code or approach you have tried ?

Comment: I'm not seeing _a lot of things_

Comment: Can any of you suggest something....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a much better Javascript immplementation:

```
var stack = [2, 48, 1, 32, 24, 12, 60];
var minPos = stack.indexOf(stack.reduce(function (a, b) { return a <= b ? a : b; }));
var maxPos = stack.indexOf(stack.reduce(function (a, b) { return a >= b ? a : b; }));
stack[minPos] = stack.splice(maxPos, 1, stack[minPos])[0];
```

Other than the line to set-up an example stack, this approach does 3 things:

1. *Find the position in the array of the 'minimum' number*. A reduce function is used to iterate over the array, reducing the array to a single result, which represents the smallest number (See the [JS Array.reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).
2. *Find the position in the array of the 'maximum' number.* This is done similar to the above, but with a reduce function that results in the highest number.
3. *Using the positions we found for 'min' and 'max', swap the elements at these positions in the array.*

Comment: Can you explain this? If you post code to a question that doesn't specify a language, it's best to not use language-specific features and syntax (like the other answer), but if you're going to, you should explain what they do. Or you can ask the question poster which language they'd like a solution in before posting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a JS implementation of a solution.

```
var myStack = [ 2, 48, 1, 32, 24, 12, 60 ];
var posMax = 0;
var maxValue = myStack[0];
var posMin = 0;
var minValue = myStack[0];
var tempStack = [ ]; // will be constructed, but in the reverse order.
var counter = 0;
do {
    var tempElement = myStack.pop();
    if(tempElement > maxValue) {
        posMax = counter;
        maxValue = tempElement;
    }
    if(tempElement < minValue) {
        posMin = counter;
        minValue = tempElement;
    }
   tempStack.push(tempElement);
   counter++;
} while(myStack.length != 0);
// Reverse the order of the temp Stack
var tempStack2 = [];
do {
   tempStack2.push(tempStack.pop());
} while (tempStack.length != 0)
tempStack = tempStack2;
// Constructing the returned Stack.
var newStack = [];
counter = 0;
do 
{

   var tempElement = tempStack.pop();

   if(counter !== posMin && counter !== posMax) {
      newStack.push(tempElement);
   }
   if(counter === posMax) {
      newStack.push(minValue);
   }
   if(counter === posMin) {
      newStack.push(maxValue);
   }
   counter++;
} while(tempStack.length != 0);

// Reverse the order of the new Stack
var result = [];
do {
   result.push(newStack.pop());
} while (newStack.length != 0);

console.log("Final:" + result);
```

Comment: but then u can only operate on the element at the top of the stack only

Comment: another thing once you have popped out an element how can you access the earlier stack

Comment: Please, see edit in the code above. I guess you will find answer to all your questions. :)

Comment: i think the reverse in tempstack2 is not neseccary size-posMax and size-posMin can also work

Comment: This is correct, but seems **to me** to be harder to understand because item are reversed ;)

Comment: This seems wildly inefficient given the other answer available.

Comment: Since the `reduce` function is specific to the Array and not useable on a `stack`, other answer seems to be "irrelevant".
See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/147647 for more informations about the difference between a stack and an array.